# Spring boot default form binding

Tags: java, spring-mvc, binding, spring-boot, converters

I have a spring boot project. I have a form where I bind an entity property using its id(Long). Like so,

```
<input name="entityProperty" value="1" ... />
```

It binds successfully when submitted (there's already an existing entity with id=1).

However, I export this project via jar file and use it in another Spring MVC project (not Spring boot). Now, I'm getting an error when binding this same scenario: `backingObject.entityProperty` is `null`.

It's similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12100107/spring-mvc-bind-id-to-an-object-in-a-model). It's suggested there that I have to create a conversion service, from Long to Type of my entity.

Do I have to do that solution also? Why didn't I have to provide that in my spring boot project? What's the default configuration for spring boot?

Answer (score 0):

I fix this by adding a custom property editor,

```
public class BaseEntityEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {}
```

However, it is still unclear to me why it works by default in my Spring Boot application.